A movie with an orphan falling overboard
Ok, this is a tough one. I remember seeing this scene on TV when I was in my early teens. Of all the vague movie memories that have plagued me over the years this is the one that I've never been able to resolve.
A group of of children, probably orphans, in roughly the 1920s are on a voyage on a large cruise liner, possibly stowed away. At some point, during the night, they all run out on deck to play. One of them, a slightly chubby boy, starts balancing on the railing, slips, and falls overboard. As I remember, it was quite a shocking moment.
The movie's main characters, as I recall, are a more handsome orphan boy and a girl. I didn't see the rest of the movie, unfortunately.
Some further notes:

I think it was a movie, but it could also have been a miniseries.
It should have been produced between 1985 and 1995, based on the look, and the time I saw it.
Considering that several hours with the advanced search on IMDb didn't yield anything, I expect it may not have been an English language film.
Production values seemed pretty high.
It's not an adaptation of Captains Courageous.
It looked like it may have been an adaptation of a book.


I vaguely recall someone asking a similar question here...

@Walt Yeah, that was me :) For some reason the question has been removed (probably when the site came out of beta). I didn't see any rules banning these kinds of questions, so I decided to re-post it.

It's possible it just got removed because ID questions without upvoted\approved\any answers are usually deleted after 28 days.

@Walt Oh really? Well, sorry for re-posting then. I wanted this question to hang around on the internet just in case somebody punches the same keywords into Google at some time in the future. I created a meta post to discuss the policy.

I dunno the rules in this case, TBH. Maybe the Mods will. Personally, if the question is detailed and well written (which yours seems to be), I don't mind it staying for now.

[Sorry, unanswered ID questions that are also inactive are closed after 28 days.]
